# como poner enlace a email que al pasar el cursor cambie color

Tags: css, html5

Hola soy nuevo en esto de Wordpress, css...
El problema que tengo es al poner el enlace de correo en el footer, apenas se aprecia el cambio de color, en el resto de la pagina se ve a la legua,lo estoy haciendo con nimble builder, ya que no hay presupuesto para nada, de momento, y el elementor no me entra.
como podria hacerlo, gracias.en html o css adicional, mientras funcione me da igual.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues sin mucha más información haría algo así:

En html tendría el enlace, imagino que algo así:

```
<a href="mailto:elcorreo@tucorreo.com" class="mi-enlace">Mi enlace de correo</a>
```

Y luego en el css algo así:

```
.mi-enlace:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

Esto es un ejemplo. Saludos

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, con lo que has puesto en la contestacion , funciona, me disculpo por no expresarme bien, pero aun asi lo has entendido muchisimas gracias Kaz

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya servido! Saludos